# Separate xs:unique from element

Tags: xml, xsd, unique, unique-constraint

I have been given an XSD that my XML needs to conform to. The XSD doesn't contain unique ID constraints.

In the example below, I added an unique ID constraint in line.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Passengers">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="passenger"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="PassengerUniqueSequnceNo">
            <xs:selector xpath="./passenger"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@SequenceNo"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="passenger">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="SequenceNo" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>`

I'd like to not have to add it in line. The goal is to minimize changes to the definition of the XSD, by adding the constraints to a different file, and importing it / including it.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.1 you could use xs:override to override the element declaration (but you would still have to repeat the part of the element declaration that is unchanged.)

Otherwise, write an XSLT transformation that adds the constraint to the schema before using the schema for validation.

Or write a validator (using any technology you like, e.g. XSLT) that just checks the uniqueness constraint, and run this as a separate pass after doing schema validation.